# Android: How to change spinner's selection with a button?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

There are a spinner and a button. When the button is clicked, I want the spinner to select some other option other than the one  it currently holds. How may I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `setSelection(index);` on your spinner where `index` is the index of the option in the options list from your button.onClick().

Comment: isn't that like, in the documentation?